# Answering questions in surveymonkey with URL variables

Tags: surveymonkey

I have to assume with SurveyMonkey you can prepopulate answers in the survey via URL variables.  For example, if I am sending out an email to my customers and one of the data points I want to have associated with my survey is email address.

Instead of the customer having to enter their email address I should be able to populate it for them.

IE surveymonkey.com/surveyname?email=blah@blah.com would fill in the Email fields with blah@blah.com

Is this possible?  If not is there a reason?  Does someone know of a survey platform that does allow this?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can provide a custom variable with the survey by using the 'c' parameter, e.g.:

surveymonkey.com/s/survey?c=

This custom id is then stored on the respondent's details.  You can put any text you like in there, including an email address.

However AFAIK you can't store other variables this way - just the custom variable.

Cheers,

Miles